Showing hinge constraint conserves system energy
Suppose we have two objects floating in space connected via an ideal hinge(IE frictionless).
Suppose they have initial conditions on their positions, orientations and current velocities.
How can it be shown that the hinge constraint does not change the energy of the system? IE the force that it creates between the two objects during state evolution neither adds or subtracts energy?
The arguments I have seen basically say that the direction of force is perpendicular to direction of motion so no work is done but this doesn't show that the system energy remains constant

"no work means no change in kinetic energy" I haven't seen a proof of that in my dynamics book.

like work done by all force is change in kinetic energy,

That shows that ideal hinges are "conservative elements" being the power of the actions zero. An ideal cylindrical hinge allows rotation only around its axis and transfers no moment around the same direction.
Thus, if you evaluate the power of the actions (both forces and moments) involved in an ideal cylindrical hinge, you get
$$\begin{aligned}
P^{ideal, cyl.hinge} & = \mathbf{F}_{12} \cdot \mathbf{v}_1+ \mathbf{F}_{21} \cdot \mathbf{v}_2+ \mathbf{M}_{12} \cdot \mathbf{\omega}_1+ \mathbf{M}_{21} \cdot \mathbf{\omega}_2 = \\
& = \mathbf{F}_{12} \cdot ( \mathbf{v}_1 -  \mathbf{v}_2 ) + \mathbf{M}_{12} \cdot ( \mathbf{\omega}_1 - \mathbf{\omega}_2 ) = \\
\end{aligned} \ ,$$
having used third principle of Newton dynamics, action/reaction $\mathbf{F}_{ij} = - \mathbf{F}_{ji}$,  $\mathbf{M}_{ij} = - \mathbf{M}_{ji}$.
Now, the first term is zero because no relative velocity between points on the hinge axis, the second one is zero because of zero moment (ideal hinge, remember) in the direction of the axis allowing relative rotation, and thus $\mathbf{M}_{12}$ and $\mathbf{\omega}_1 - \mathbf{\omega}_2$ are orthogonal and their inner product zero.
The same proof holds for every ideal constraint. Power of internal reactions is zero, because for any of the 6 dofs in 3D space either the component of action or or the component of relative motion are zero.
For completeness, the equations of motion composed of 2 rigid bodies are
$$\begin{cases}
 m_1 \dot{\mathbf{v}}_1 = \mathbf{F}^e_1 + \mathbf{F}_{12} \\
 \frac{d}{dt} \mathbb{I}_1 \cdot \mathbf{\omega}_1 = \mathbf{M}_1^e + \mathbf{M}_{12}
\end{cases} \qquad , \qquad
\begin{cases}
 m_1 \dot{\mathbf{v}}_2 = \mathbf{F}^e_2 + \mathbf{F}_{21} \\
 \frac{d}{dt} \mathbb{I}_2 \cdot \mathbf{\omega}_2 = \mathbf{M}_2^e + \mathbf{M}_{21} \ .
\end{cases}$$
Performing scalar products of the momentum equations with the velocity of the center of masses $\mathbf{v}_1$, $\mathbf{v}_2$, and the angular momentum equations with the angular velocity of the bodies, and summing, we get the theorem of the kinetic energy,
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \frac{d}{dt} \underbrace{\left[ \frac{1}{2}m_1|\mathbf{v}_1|^2 +  \frac{1}{2}m_1|\mathbf{v}_2|^2 + \frac{1}{2} \omega_1 \cdot \mathbb{I}_1 \cdot \omega_1 + \frac{1}{2} \omega_2 \cdot \mathbb{I}_2 \cdot \omega_2 \right]}_{ =K} = \\
& = \underbrace{\mathbf{F}_1^e \cdot \mathbf{v}_1 +  \mathbf{F}_2^e \cdot \mathbf{v}_2 + \mathbf{M}_1^e \cdot \mathbf{\omega}_1 +  \mathbf{M}_2^e \cdot \mathbf{\omega}_2}_{P^e} + \underbrace{\mathbf{F}_{12} \cdot \mathbf{v}_1 +  \mathbf{F}_{21} \cdot \mathbf{v}_2 + \mathbf{M}_{12} \cdot \mathbf{\omega}_1 +  \mathbf{M}_{21} \cdot \mathbf{\omega}_2}_{P^i = 0}
\end{aligned}$$
having defined the kinetic energy of the system, the power of externa actions and the power of internal actions, here zero if due to ideal constraints. In general in classical mechanics, it's possible define the mechanical energy of a system as the sum of the kinetic and potential energy,  $E^{mech} := K + V$, here the potential energy of the internal actions are zero, and the mechanical energy equals the kinetic energy, so that the following holds
$$\frac{d K}{dt} = P^{tot} = P^e + \underbrace{P^i}_{=0}$$
$$\frac{d E^{mech}}{dt} = P^e$$

Ok but this isnt showing the total energy of the system hasn't changed, there is still a missing connection between total energy(IE rotational and translational). I agree that no work is done etc, but there is still a missing piece.

The total energy hasn't changed w.r.t. which condition? Loosely speaking, "conservative elements" means that their power can be written as a time derivative of a potential energy. Since the power of ideal constraints is identically zero - and if you really wish, you can write zero as the time derivative of a constant function - they're conservative elements
